# How to create filter on layer with dynamic properties

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, maplibre-gl

From a source in geojson (points features only), I want to create a filter with dynamic properties,  with AND and OR conditions.

My code :

```
let filter = ['any'];
currentLayerFilters.forEach(function (layers) {
    filter.push(['==', layer, ['get', 'layerType']]);
});
```

And in map.addLayer() :

```
filter: [
    'all',
    ['has', 'point_count'],
    filter
],
```

The filter `['has', 'point_count']` is mandatory so need to be true.
Filters in "any" have to be least 1 at true to show the point.

On the map, i don't have any error, and no point is on the map.
What filter i need to create ? I try with filter '==' and 'in', but no difference.

I 'console.log' variable filter and it contains valid filters with the layerType in the geojson.

Comment: Can we have an example of the data set?